# How to *easily* display Korean characters in a Java program

Tags: java, unicode, mac-roman

I'd like to do this:

> System.out.println("안녕하세요!");

But I get a "Some characters could not be encoded using the MacRoman character encoding" popup error message when I try to compile in Eclipse. I'm running Mac OS X. Is there a way to get around that?

So, I guess I'll try using Unicode:

> System.out.println((char)0xD0A4);

Which I'd like to print out '키', but instead get a '?'. I guess the command line doesn't support Unicode. But even if it did, it'd be really annoying to have to go to one of several charts ([like this one](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UAC00.pdf)) to find each character block.

Anyway, FINE! So I'll use a JLabel...

> JLabel lbl = new
>   JLabel(""+(char)0xD0A4);

Awesome, this prints out 키! ... but I still have to look up the Unicode characters for each block. How can I easily spew out Korean characters in a program?

Comment: This [link](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050208053951714) might be of help!

Comment: Which terminal program are you using?  Which encodings have you enabled it to use - Preferences / Encodings)?  I use /Applications/Utilities/Terminal and have a variety of encodings enabled, including UTF-8 (and MacRoman, and Korean EUC).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch to UTF-8, as said before.
However, instead of doing it on a per-project basis (as J-16) suggests, go through
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace and change the "Text file encoding" to "Other: UTF-8".

This changes the setting for the entire workspace.
Afterwards, you can input your characters as you are used to.

Comment: Make sure that you back up everything beforehand.  When you do this, you can expect all of your non-ASCII characters to become garbled.  Pasting them in from another source AFTER switching encodings is fine.

Comment: Yes, bdares, that is a very helpful suggestion.

Comment: I am trying to print korean currency symbol in a downloaded csv file. It always replaces the currency symbol with '?'. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse console doesn't use unicode encoding so it can't display those.  See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13865.

Try the fix mentioned here: http://paranoid-engineering.blogspot.com/2008/05/getting-unicode-output-in-eclipse.html

Answer (score 1):

Just right click the file in the project view, choose properties. Change the encoding to UTF8 there.